# JQuery DataTables plugin issue

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have encountered a strange problem with the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').dataTable({
    "bProcessing":true,
    "sAjaxSource":'http://localhost/utcms/json_source2.txt'});
 });
});
```

This code loads the data into the table if I run the page in safari no problem. My issue is that if I run the same page through django with a render_to_response all I get is the processing sign no data. upon debugging it simply says: Failed to load resource: Cancelled.

Its not an issue with not being able to find the source file, I've also discounted the possibility of an issue resulting from rendering the page and disrupting the fetch process. I must be missing something in datatable setup. its strange that it works on a static page but not on a django rendered page even though it sees the file otherwise it would generate a 404 for that file on debug.

Any suggestions would be welcome

Cheers

Chris

PS: I am new to JQuery and DataTables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a work around if anyone else is having similar difficulty. It ain't elegant but it works.

Grab the JSON response from the JQuery request function and parse it and load it into the table as an Array. As I say it isn't elegant but it works.

Comment: I have just discovered that this issue has been caused by a scripting issue with having the development site on localhost:8000 and the file generated on localhost. (cross site scripting error, I think its called)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add a [mimetype option](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#id2) to render_to_response :

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    return render_to_response('myapp/utcms/json_source2.txt', {"foo": "bar"},
        mimetype="application/json")
```

I you use a lot Jquery DataTables and its server-side processing feature as I do too, you really should check [these utilities for Django](http://www.assembla.com/code/datatables_demo/subversion/nodes/trunk/1_6_2/datatables_demo/demo/utils.py?rev=5). When installed, it all boils down to use a few lines of code and passing it a queryset.